# Is it possible to add text to a model in the UV image editor without external texture file?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Is there a method or addon that allows me to add text to a model's UV without needing to go into an image editing program to make the text an image texture?

I want to create some 2D holographic signs, I've seen a video showing a pretty good method for making 2d holographic signs but it involves making text into an image texture and then going through the node process to make it which i can do if its the best way.

I also could use such an ability to add text to weapons or other surfaces if it were possible.

Comment: the only thing i know is make a 2nd scene, add a text object + cam and render it as your own image, so you don't have to use an external program

Comment: thats kind of what i expected, oh well its not a huge deal to make textures to use for that purpose